# Troca de imagens utilizando js

Tags: javascript, html, imagem

Estou tentando alterar a imagem de acordo com os horários porem não está funcionando alguém consegue me ajudar? as imagens são respectivas aos seus horários,
segue o código logo a baixo

`<body onload="carregar()">`

```
<header>
    <h1>Hora do dia</h1>
</header>

<section>
    <div id="msg">
        aqui vai aparecer a msg
    </div>
    <div id="imagem">
        <img src="fotomanha.png" alt="Foto de manhã">
    </div>
</section>

<footer>
    <p>&copy; On</p>
</footer>

<script>
    function carregar() {
var msg = document.getElementById('msg')
var img = document.getElementById('imagem')
var data = new Date()
var hora = data.getHours()
msg.innerHTML = `Agora são ${hora} horas.`

if (hora >= 0 && hora < 12) {
    //Bom dia
    img.src = 'fotomanha.png'
} else if (hora >= 12 && hora < 18) {
    //Boa tarde
    img.src = 'fototarde.png'
} else {
    //Boa noite
    img.src = 'fotonoite.png'
}
```

}

```
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

na variável `img`  você tá pegando a `div` e não o elemento `<img />` para pegar o elemento `img` só fazer assim
`var img = document.querySelector('#imagem > img')`